# AJAX отправить Массив

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть такой код.

```
var anum = ["значение1", "значение2", "значение3"];
    $.ajax({
        url: "handler.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            anum: anum
    },
        method: "POST"
    })
            .done(function (data) {
              alert('ok');
            });
```

Как послать массив в скрипт php ?

Comment: там ты же уже посылаешь

Comment: не обрабатывается в php

Comment: что значит не обрабатывается? значит не так "обрабатываешь"

Comment: Обрабатываю как обычно, весь код писал не я, поэтому не могу понять в чем дело, читал что надо сериализовать через json но не понял что да как

Comment: `Обрабатываю как обычно,`- как обычно это как? мы не знаем, как вы *обычно* обрабатываете

Comment: дело именно в том что строка обрабатывается а вот массив нет, мне было интересно правильный ли запрос ajax я посылаю вообще или нет

Comment: Да правильный. Точнее один из вариантов правильных запросов. Но намёки не помогли... давай напрямую. Что у тебя написано в PHP?

Comment: Может массив неправильный? Это же `JS` массив — `JSON`'ом даже и не пахнет.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй свойство у аякса traditional=true указать

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   traditional: true 
   ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP парсит json в объект или в массив (зависит от второго параметра функции json_decode). Однако если на вход поступает массив то независимо от параметра будет массив. Возможно Ваш бэкэнд пытается получить доступ как к объекту.

Попробуйте так

```
var anum = {query: ["значение1", "значение2", "значение3"]};
```

Answer (score -2):

Есть вероятность, что у вас ошибка на стороне сервера по причине несоответствия указанного типа данных `dataType` и самих данных (вы передаете массив, а не JSON как таковой), а вы эту ошибку не ловите, так как используете callback `done` вместо `success`, это легко проверить немного поправив код:

```
.done(function (data) {
          alert('ok');  // эту строку заменить на alert(data); или console.log(data)
        }); .
```

Как вариант, если данные обязательно нужно передать именно как JSON, в вашем случае можно сделать так: `var anum = JSON.parse((["значение1", "значение2", "значение3"]).join())`